# How should we tag questions that ask about printing the command before executing it?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions

How should we tag questions that ask about printing the command before executing it? The answer would refer to something like: `bash -x`, `psql --echo-all`, etc., depending on the language.

I feel that there should be a tag for this, perhaps [logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/logging), [trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trace) or [printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/printing).

Examples:

- [How can I print each command before executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5750450/967621)
- [Make a Bash script echo executed commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9823246/967621)
- [How to echo shell commands as they are executed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2853803/967621)
- [Printing to screen in .sql file in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17383056/967621)

Comment: Have you considered that there should be a *single canonical question* about this, rather than a tag to group together questions that are all asking how to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 10):

No. Don’t be ridiculous. This is not a thing that needs a tag. Nobody is an expert in “printing commands before they are executed”. Nobody wants to search for questions about “printing commands before they are executed”. Just tag with the language.

Comment: Are there experts in logging or printing? Yet there are tags for this. Have you considered this?

Comment: I have considered it and rejected it as irrelevant.

Comment: @TimurShtatland Have you considered why the [burninate-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request) tag exists?

Comment: @Gimby Why is this relevant to the OP?